# How to fix infinite loop error?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel, infinite-loop

I have a script, and it is preventing me from accessing urls such as example.com/hi that are not part of the script.

How can I add an exception so that these urls work? This is my htaccess right now.

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: You `shouldn't` technically need to exclude them if they are `real` directories. That's what the conditions are for.

Comment: The script handles all incoming requests, so any url results in an infinite loop. Do you know of any solution?

Comment: index.php is not a real file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional rewrite conditions to exclude certain URLs. For example:

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hi/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If that still doesn't work you can place a `.htaccess` file with the content `RewriteEngine Off` inside the folder.

Comment: It is still giving me the error. Is there another way? This script handles all incoming requests.

Comment: I'm going to need more details. How does your custom script (under `hi`) look like?

Comment: The script is on example.com, and I have a sitemap generator installed on example.com/sitemap

Comment: No it's definitely not. Maybe that's a domain you set up locally?

Comment: Yes. I have the script on the domain. Then I added another script that I want to access at domain.com/sitemap, but it gives me the infinite loop error.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you without seeing the script that's causing the error

Comment: Thanks, but this still isn't going to help. I need to see your code.

Comment: Why is that? How can I make it work on just sitemap?

Comment: I don't know. You can try placing a `.htaccess` file with the content `RewriteEngine Off` inside the sitemap folder.